# Cassandra-cli cant connect to remote cassandra server

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have a cassandra server running on a server(serv1). cassandra-cli can connect to it when run on serv1. However, when i try to connect to it through some other server(serv2), i get the following exception:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.connect(CliMain.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:256)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
    ... 3 more
Exception connecting to jckstore/9160. Reason: Connection refused.
```

I looked in cassandra.yaml and found that the property "listen_address" is configured to "localhost" and using 0.0.0.0 is severely discouraged. I tried to change localhost to serv2, ip address of serv1 but nothing worked. Even commenting out didnt help.

Is there a way i can make my cassandra server listen on all the ip's without using 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem as following:

1. changing the rpc_address property in cassandra.yaml to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost.
2. set the broadcast_rpc_address property in cassandra.yaml to a value other than 0.0.0.0

Then I can access.

Comment: What do you mean other than 0.0.0.0.. what did you set it to?

Comment: In the yaml file, the address is 1.2.3.4 in the comment. I set it to 255.255.255.255, and it works , well... at least for the moment

Answer (score 4):

Cassandra cli uses thrift to connect to Cassandra. The rpc_address decides how the thrift clients can connect to Cassandra. Setting it to 0.0.0.0 will work, but setting it to the hostname of the server and then using the same hostname to connect will also work.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and I was constantly surprised because it was configured correctly. In the end, I found out it was permission issues:

```
chown -R cassandra: /var/lib/cassandra
chown -R cassandra: /var/log/cassandra
```

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed this by updating the snappy temp dir VM option to point to the right directory.

```
VM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/home/users/local/user/cassandra_home/snap
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem "Connection refused". Changing the rpc_address from "localhost" to the same hostname as listen_address worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem "Connection refused". Changing start_rpc: to true fixed it for me.